# How to make a specific option unselectable programmatically with Selectize.js?

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I have a select with several options and I try to make some of the options unselectable programmatically. For instance, my code is :

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<script>
  $('select').selectize();
</script>
```

My question is: how can I make to get option "2" disabled (i.e. not displaying and not selectable) programmatically? -- I tried this code...

```
$('select')[0].selectize.$dropdown_content.find('[data-value="2"]').removeAttr('data-selectable');
```

... but it does not work (when I inspect the DOM I see that option "2" has no 'data-selectable' attribute, but it still renders and is selectable...).

Am I wrong here? And if so: what is the proper way to make an option unselectable (I can't find it anywhere in the doc)?

(I created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/j8YUA/3/)

Comment: set `display` to `none`.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, but that does not work too. I created a jsFiddle to easily reproduce my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/j8YUA/1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`disabledField`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#data_searching) setting to make a selectize option "unselectable" programmatically when rendering the options. You can also make an option "unselectable" after the fact using the [`updateOption`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_options) method (or you can simply remove the option using the [`removeOption`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_options) method) For example:

```js
const options = [
  {name: 'Option 1', disable: false},
  {name: 'Option 2', disable: true}
  ];

const sel = $('#select1').selectize({
  options: options,
  valueField: 'name',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: ['name'],
  disabledField: 'disable'
});

$('#button1').click(() => {
  sel[0].selectize.updateOption('Option 1', {name: 'Option 1', disable: true});
});

$('#button2').click(() => {
  sel[0].selectize.removeOption('Option 2');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Selectize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>Option 2 disabled</div>
    <input id="select1" name="select1" type="text" />
    <button id="button1">Disable Option 1</button>
    <button id="button2">Remove Option 2</button>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer is very close to what I'm trying to do, but is it possible to hide the option instead of disabling it? I'm mainly asking for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725670/how-to-set-a-selectize-option-to-displaynone

Comment: @JohnOdom - you can remove the option completely using the `removeOption` method. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: No, but I'm aware of that. I think I have a working solution that I'll put up on my question once I finish testing it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `disabledField` is not implemented. alternatively, you can add a `disabled` property to the option you want to disable, and do the following:

```
$('#control').selectize({
  render: {
    option: function(item, escape) {
      if (item.disabled) {
        return '<div style="pointer-events: none; color: #aaa;">' + escape(item.label) + '</div>';
      }

      return '<div>' + escape(item.label) + '</div>';
    }
  }
});
```

(source: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/224)

Answer (score -1):

Selectize options are stored in object `$('select')[0].selectize.options`, so to delete an option you should delete respective property from options object

```
 delete $('select')[0].selectize.options["2"];
```