# How to hide a selectize option programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, selectize.js

I currently have a selectize drop-down that is suppose to have some options in it disabled and hidden depending on a list of strings that I have. Here is the non-selectize javascript function that I tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select onchange="ToggleSelectizeOptions(this.value)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
    <option value="honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="porsche">Porsche</option>
  </select>

  <select id="selectize">
    <option value="">All Vehicles</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
    <option value="honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="porsche">Porsche</option>
  </select>

  <script>
    function ToggleSelectizeOptions(ids) {
      var selectizeOptions = document.getElementById("selectize").options;
      var selectizeSingleOption;

      //We always start at 1 because index 0 always have "" as the value.
      for (var idx = 1; idx < selectizeOptions.length; idx++) {
        selectizeSingleOption = selectizeOptions[idx];
        if (ids) {
          if (ids.includes(selectizeSingleOption.value)) {
            selectizeSingleOption.style.display = "";
          } else {
            selectizeSingleOption.style.display = "none";
          }
        } else {
          selectizeSingleOption.style.display = "";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This works with dropdowns that are not selectize controls but I'm looking for a solution that would use selectize.js to do the same thing.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568258/how-to-make-a-specific-option-unselectable-programmatically-with-selectize-js?rq=1) that is similar to what I want, except the answer disables the option while I want to hide the option.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added code snippet to show that the code works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to "hide" selectize options (with display css or otherwise) other than simply removing them from the `options` array that is created when you initialize a selectize control. If that is all that you need to do, then you can remove a selectize option by using the selectize [`removeOption(value)`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_options) method (see the working snippet below for an example).

Based on your code example, it looks like your ultimate goal is to create cascading dropdowns. If so, see the 2nd snippet below for an example.

```js
const sel1 = $('#select1').selectize();
sel1[0].selectize.removeOption('ford');
sel1[0].selectize.refreshOptions();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Selectize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="select1">
      <option value="ford">Ford</option>
      <option value="honda">Honda</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

If your ultimate goal is to create cascading dropdowns where the value selected in the first `select` element determines which options are available in a second `select` element. The snippet below initializes the options in the javascript rather than the html.

```js
const models = [{text: 'Models', value: ''}];
const makes = [
  {text: 'Makes', value: ''},
  {text: 'Ford', value: 'ford'},
  {text: 'Honda', value: 'honda'}
];

const modelsByMake = {
  ford: [
    {text: 'Explorer', value: 'explorer'},
    {text: 'Expedition', value: 'expedition'}
  ],
  honda: [
    {text: 'Civic', value: 'civic'},
    {text: 'Accord', value: 'accord'}
  ]
};

const sel2 = $('#select2').selectize({
  options: models,
  items: [''],
  valueField: 'value',
  labelField: 'text',
  sortField: 'value',
  searchField: ['text'],
  load: (query, callback) => {
    let options = [];
    $.each(modelsByMake, (i, v) => {
      options = options.concat(v);
    });
    
    callback(options);
  },
  preload: true
});

const sel1 = $('#select1').selectize({
  options: makes,
  items: [''],
  valueField: 'value',
  labelField: 'text',
  sortField: 'value',
  searchField: ['text'],
  onChange: (value) => {
    let options = models;
    if (value) {
      // get models for selected make
      options = options.concat(modelsByMake[value]);
    } else {
      // get all models
      $.each(modelsByMake, (i, v) => {
         options = options.concat(v);
      });
    }
    
    sel2[0].selectize.clear(); // clear sel2 selected items
    sel2[0].selectize.clearOptions(); // clear sel2 options
    
    // load options corresponding to sel1 value in sel2
    sel2[0].selectize.load((callback) => {
      callback(options);
    });
    
    // refresh sel2 options list
    sel2[0].selectize.refreshOptions();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Selectize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="select1"></select>
    <select id="select2"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your cascading dropdown solution is more like what I wanted. I just hoped I didn't need to keep track of the original list of options. An example that I had in mind was that the first drop down could have an option called "All Makes" which would show all available models in the second drop down. If I pick "Ford" as my make then it should show only Ford models but if I switch back to "All Makes" it would show all available models again.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, but I was wondering if there is a way to grab the current list of options so that way I could revert the 2nd dropdown back to the original list whenever I need to?

Comment: @JohnOdom - I see... edited answer to include functions that display all models when no make is selected (includes change to enable users to select "Makes" or "Models" in order to reset the dropdown - rather than using placeholders). You can use something similar to the approaches in the `load` and `onChange` functions if you need to reset the list of models based on some other action.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful to me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task - hide or remove some selectized options.
The @benvc solution works for me, but it displays a dropdown, as if it was pressed.

**Improved version:**

```
const sel1 = $('#select1').selectize();
sel1[0].selectize.removeOption('ford');
sel1[0].selectize.refreshOptions(false);
```

**Explanation:**

As the documentation says it has a boolean parameter triggerDropdown:

> refreshOptions(triggerDropdown)
>
> ...
>
> triggerDropdown   boolean

https://selectize.dev/docs/API/selectize#refreshoptionstriggerdropdown

Setting it to false prevents a dropdown from appearing.
It worked even without refreshOptions() call. But I decided to keep it.