# Is there a better way to condense these <select> pairs, of two types?

Tags: javascript, structure

I'm wanting to see if there's a better way to write this, solely in Javascript.

There are two kinds of sets, the first set (C7, T7, C11, T11) have four options in the first select, and then up to two options in the second set.

The second set (14X, 17X) have eight options in the first select, and then up to four options in the second set.

Note, I can't change the values as these are being used for a calculator.

```js
//Set C7
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.getElementById("C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
    bench = document.getElementById("C7-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});

// Set T7
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.getElementById("T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
    bench = document.getElementById("T7-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});

// Set C11
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.getElementById("C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
    bench = document.getElementById("C11-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});

// Set T11
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.getElementById("T11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
    bench = document.getElementById("T11-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});

// Set 14X
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.getElementById("14X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
    bench = document.getElementById("14X-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 4 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 4 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});

// Set 17X
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.getElementById("17X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
    bench = document.getElementById("17X-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 4 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 4 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <br /> Set C7
</div>

<select id="C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="C7-Under-Drawer-Bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br /> Set T7
</div>

<select id="T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="T7-Under-Drawer-Bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br /> Set C11
</div>

<select id="C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="C11-Under-Drawer-Bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br /> Set T11
</div>

<select id="T11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="T11-Under-Drawer-Bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br /> Set 14X
</div>

<select id="14X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x5">combo-x5</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x6">combo-x6</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x7">combo-x7</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x8">combo-x8</option>
</select>

<select id="14X-Under-Drawer-Bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x3</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x4</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br /> Set 17X
</div>

<select id="17X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x5">combo-x5</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x6">combo-x6</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x7">combo-x7</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x8">combo-x8</option>
</select>

<select id="17X-Under-Drawer-Bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x3</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x4</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated - thank you!

Also - this is a follow-on from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963642/how-to-limit-options-based-on-a-select-based-on-another-select-without-chan/67963908#67963908) here if interested:

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Awesome, thanks heaps @Barmar I wondered if there was a place like this. Thank you for sharing :)